# Find the max amount of all averaged results in MySQL (BigQuery)

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have averaged rates for properties by day. I would like to find the averaged property that has the highest rate per day:

```
select Prop_Name as property, arrival_date as arrival, round(avg(Rate)) as rate
from [SomeDataBase] 
where [Timestamp] >= '2015-06-15 00:00:00.000' 
and [Timestamp] <= '2015-06-20 23:59:59.000'  
group by property, arrival 
order by arrival asc limit 10;
```

so I am returning the following:

```
Property             Date              Rate
Prop_One    2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    281.0     
Prop_Two    2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    343.0     
Prop_Three  2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    266.0     
Prop_One    2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    87.0  
Prop_Three  2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    132.0     
Prop_Two    2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    80.0
```

I'd like to return the max rate for each day without a day repeating:

```
Prop_Three  2015-06-15 00:00:00 UTC    400.0     
Prop_One    2015-06-16 00:00:00 UTC    586.0     
Prop_Three  2015-06-17 00:00:00 UTC    190.0     
Prop_Two    2015-06-18 00:00:00 UTC    180.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think bigquery supports `row_number()`, so I think this will work:

```
select t.*
from (select Prop_Name as property, arrival_date as arrival,
             round(avg(Rate)) as rate,
             row_number() over (partition by arrival_date order by avg(rate) desc) as seqnum
      from [SomeDataBase] 
      where [Timestamp] >= '2015-06-15' and
            [Timestamp] < '2015-06-21'  
      group by property, arrival 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

Arrgh.  The above is standard SQL, but the following might work in Bigquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by arrival_date order by rate desc) as seqnum
      from (select Prop_Name as property, arrival_date as arrival,
                   round(avg(Rate)) as rate
            from [SomeDataBase] 
            where [Timestamp] >= '2015-06-15' and
                  [Timestamp] < '2015-06-21'  
            group by property, arrival 
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "In analytic expression, ORDER BY must refer to named columns. Found AVG"

Comment: @FF4Fanatic That would normally land under a new question, not a comment on an answer. In any case, chances are you'll need to rename the column that is your AVG (say, something like select avg(rate) as arate) and later on, order by arate. You can't have a function in an orderby, it NEEDS to be a called column. You can always use nested sub-queries to transform your avg into a named column if you wantà

Comment: @Patrice . . . In my opinion, it is a perfectly reasonable comment.  The original query used ANSI standard SQL syntax, which BigQuery does not support.  Hopefully, it supports the modified query.

Comment: Even modified query won't work in BQ, since BQ wants ORDER BY inside window function to use column name only, not expression.